# How to run LLVM interpreter with a shared library?

Tags: llvm, dynamic-linking, lli

I have `mylib.c` file which has some functions. I want to use those functions from my `.c` file as external ones in compiled llvm code. I'm playing with LLVM interpreter (`lli-4.0`) and I wonder how can I tell `lli` to use functions from my `.c` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lli` has a `-load` argument so you compile your C file to a dynamic library and then just do

```
lli -load path-to-your-dynamic-library ....
```

Comment: Interestingly the `--extra-object` doesn't work but feels like it should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`lli` supports the following args,

- `-extra-module` for loading bitcode modules
- `-extra-object` for loading object files
- `-extra-archive` for loading static libs.