# LLVM Interepreter (lli) and shared object loading

Tags: c, linker, clang, llvm, lli

I'm trying to use `lli` to interpret/JIT-compile a bitcode file `a.bc` that uses functions defined in a shared object `afl-llvm-rt.so`. When I try to use lli like this

```
lli -dlopen ./afl-llvm-rt.so a.bc
```

I get:

```
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: lli -load ./afl-llvm-rt.o a.bc 
#0 0x00007fa2a620f833 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1+0xa99833)
#1 0x00007fa2a620dbe0 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1+0xa97be0)
#2 0x00007fa2a620fe65 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1+0xa99e65)
#3 0x00007fa2a57683c0 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x153c0)
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  lli -load ./afl-llvm-rt.o a.bc
```

Further investigation with `gdb` reveals that the function addresses are not set:

```
> gdb lli
(gdb) r -load ./afl-llvm-rt.o a.bc
Starting program: /usr/bin/lli -load ./afl-llvm-rt.o a.bc
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7fca021 in sancov.module_ctor_trace_pc_guard ()
#2  0x00007ffff4f46118 in llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::GenericValue>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff4ef9a57 in llvm::ExecutionEngine::runStaticConstructorsDestructors(llvm::Module&, bool) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff4f4587f in llvm::MCJIT::runStaticConstructorsDestructors(bool)
    () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1
#5  0x000000000041391b in main ()
```

However, if I compile the file as usual, with `clang a.bc ./afl-llvm-rt.so`, the output executable works just fine.

How do I make `lli` dynamically link `a.bc` with `afl-llvm-rt.so`?

EDIT:
I compiled `afl-llvm-rt.so` to be a LLVM IR file instead, then I used `llvm-link a.bc afl-llvm-rt.bc -o result.bc` to link them together. After that, I tried `lli result.bc`, which gives the following:

```
ocelaiwo@E490:~/Misc/ff> lli result.bc
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: lli result.bc 
#0 0x00007efc8d3d9833 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1+0xa99833)
#1 0x00007efc8d3d7be0 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1+0xa97be0)
#2 0x00007efc8d3d9e65 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1+0xa99e65)
#3 0x00007efc8c9323c0 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x153c0)
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  lli result.bc
```

But if I `clang result.bc -o result`, the `result` executable executes just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `--load` option to lli, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44189388/7401700). Example code that would use the glib library:

```
lli --load=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so my-bicode-file.bc
```

I've also found that the option `-force-interpreter` serves as a useful debugging tip, e.g it can show the missing symbol:

```
LLVM ERROR: Could not resolve external global address: some_external_symbol
```

You can  then investigate where that symbol (e.g function) might be on your system.